# Multi Website/Store: On onepage checkout show base currency amount

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I've Created 2 Store in site & both store have different currency

1st Store Currency: **GBP**

2nd Store Currency: **US Doller**

When I've purchase & one checkout at 2nd Store it show base currency amount with message **"Your credit card will be charged for"**

For payment it transfer base currency(GBP) price but I want to transfer US Doller price to payment gateway.

[image]

Comment: You may be issue any third party extension  and that may be create issue

Comment: Site Default base currency is GBP. & the GBP price is passes to payment gateway

Comment: You can set base currency for the second store as US Dollar and then you can checkout with store view currency (US Dollar). However, Magento default does not support this function. Therefore, an extension is necessary in this issue. You can read more about Magento Multiple Store View Pricing to find the best solution.
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-store-view-pricing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this two stores, ***your base currency is GBP and in Magento***, for **Your credit card will be charged**  section , price is  taken from **base_grand_total** field. **that why showing 39.95 at there**.

You need show  only `grand_total` instead of **base_grand_total**.

If you using **any 3rd party payment gateways**,then you need to  send grand_total to *payment gateway.*

For paypal,**Magento send the base_grand_total**

Set the if condition to false

**if($this->needDisplayBaseGrandtotal()):** change to **if (false):**

**Path:** \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\onepagecheckout\onepage\review\total.phtml